# L'Hospital's rule only works if the functions are "straight"?

Tags: calculus, limits

I think I get how L'Hospital's rule works, at an intuitive level based on the ratios of the derivatives being equivalent to the ratios of the functions and therefore the limit at a point where they would otherwise evaluate to 0/0, so I am happy there. However while learning about it I see something odd in certain explanations, like here:

https://youtu.be/Hu0z-sFfF8Y?t=334

and here

https://youtu.be/kfF40MiS7zA?t=881

If the derivatives are known, then this further criteria or observation of functions "looking like a line" or "being straight" when you "zoom in" doesn't really mean anything here does it? Either you have the derivatives where f(x)/g(x) = 0/0 or you don't. And if you do, L'Hopital's rule applies.

Since we are not using infinitesimals here, then "zooming in" seems like a really sloppy idea here. epsilon delta is at work and this idea of straightness or line-like behavior is meaningless if the derivative is known.

right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The function looks like a line when we zoom in" is a hand-wavey, naively intuitive way of saying the function is differentiable at that point. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

By Taylor, a function is approximately linear in a small neighborhood, and the more you zoom in, the more the nonlinear term vanishes:

$$f(x+h)=f(x)+hf'(x)+o(h).$$

Now if you consider the ratio of two functions that vanish at the point considered,

$$\frac{f(x+h)}{g(x+h)}=\frac{f(x)+hf'(x)+o(h)}{g(x)+hg'(x)+o(h)}=\frac{f'(x)+\dfrac{o(h)}h}{g'(x)+\dfrac{o(h)}h}$$

so that the ratio tends to the ratio of the slopes.

When the functions aren't locally linear, this doesn't work.

Comment: Is "aren't locally linear" synonymous with "non differentiable"?